# JPA - Run sql NativeQuery of 'insert into' with special charters is failed

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using hibernate and mysql
when I run the following statement in mysql it works perfectly:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, is_visited) VALUES ('visit our site \'n\' days',true);
```

However, When I run with hibernate native query I get error:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'days',true)' at line 1.

Here is the java code:

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, is_visited) VALUES ('visit our site \'n\' days',true)";
    
    Query nativeQuery = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query);
    nativeQuery.executeUpdate();
```

When I change the query statement to

```
 "INSERT INTO table1 (name, is_visited) VALUES ('visit our site \'n days',true)";
```

it works.

looks like there is an issue with `\'n\'`
any idea?

Comment: Can you include the actual Java code?

Comment: I have added. thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that the following query is correctly escaping the single quotes when run directly on MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, is_visited) VALUES ('visit our site \'n\' days', true);
```

This works on MySQL because one valid way to escape literal quotes on MySQL is to escape them with backslash.  However, doing this inside a Java string means that the `\'` are not being passed to MySQL.  Instead, Java consumes the single backslash, and just the single quotes make it across to the database.  I suggest using the other method of escaping single quotes here, which is to double them up:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, is_visited) VALUES ('visit our site ''n''x days', true)";
```

While it might be possible to escape the backslashes from Java, that seems confusing to me, because it requires keeping track of escaping across both your Java and database layer.

As another general comment, if you used the Hibernate ORM layer to do the insert, or used a prepared statement, you wouldn't have to worry about this escaping problem.